# I want a different title to appear in the navigation bar for each imageview in my scroll view (xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0)

Tags: ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a scroll view, and when a user moves from one imageview to the next, I want the title in the navigation bar to change.  So I want to set a new title for the navigation bar for each image in the scroll view.  How would I go about doing this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a delegate for your scroll view.  In the delegate, implement the [`scrollViewDidScroll:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a) method to figure out which image is currently visible and change the title.

To eliminate your incompatible type warning, you can declare that `ScrollViewController` adopts the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface ScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Hey Rob, as a test, I set up the method:

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1 {
    int Position = (scrollView1.contentOffset.x);
    if (Position == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Data 1"); }    
    else if (Position == 320) {
        NSLog(@"Data 2"); 
    }}

in my scrollview.m file.  Then in viewDidLoad I used the command:

 scrollView.delegate = self;

This appears to be working, however, I am receiving a soft error (yellow exclamation mark), that reads:  Passing "Scroll View Controller" *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UIScrollViewDelegate>'.

Comment: You can edit your question to include your code, instead of putting it in a comment.  I have edited my answer to explain how to eliminate the warning.